# HAProxy Lua can't add action on <tcp-request connect>

Tags: haproxy

I have lua script for haproxy which check ip in whitelist and i need add this to haproxy config.
I need do this on tcp connection, and as the [haproxy blog](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/5-ways-to-extend-haproxy-with-lua/#actions) post says - i can do this.

```
tcp-request connection <action>
tcp-request content <action>
tcp-response content <action>
http-request <action>
http-response <action>
```

But if i use `tcp-request connection lua.checkip`  - haproxy can't start with error message:

`haproxy[9384]: [ALERT] 124/000121 (9384) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:42] : 'tcp-request connection' expects 'accept', 'reject', 'track-sc0' ... 'track-sc2', 'sc-inc-gpc0(*)', 'sc-inc-gpc1(*)', 'sc-set-gpt0(*)', 'set-src', 'set-src-port', 'set-dst', 'set-dst-port', 'silent-drop' in frontend 'haproxy_rserve' (got 'lua.checkip').`

***But i can use `tcp-request content lua.checkip`  and this working.***

As far as I understand these 2 functions must have differences and for me best solution is `connetion` or can I use `content` ?
I'm trying to build a highly loaded system, so I would not want to screw up at the configuration stage.

This lines i try add to frontend:

```
tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
tcp-request connection lua.checkip
tcp-request connection reject if { var(req.blocked) -m bool }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at [the source](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/fc0b8f39a6497f89cab338fc515f4a922cadecc2/src/hlua.c#L7312-L7323) reveals that registering a Lua `tcp-req` action is indeed just for content, and there's no way to register a Lua action for a connection:

```c
        if (strcmp(lua_tostring(L, -1), "tcp-req") == 0)
            tcp_req_cont_keywords_register(akl);
        else if (strcmp(lua_tostring(L, -1), "tcp-res") == 0)
            tcp_res_cont_keywords_register(akl);
        else if (strcmp(lua_tostring(L, -1), "http-req") == 0)
            http_req_keywords_register(akl);
        else if (strcmp(lua_tostring(L, -1), "http-res") == 0)
            http_res_keywords_register(akl);
        else
            WILL_LJMP(luaL_error(L, "Lua action environment '%s' is unknown. "
                                    "'tcp-req', 'tcp-res', 'http-req' or 'http-res' "
                                    "are expected.", lua_tostring(L, -1)));
```

The function that it'd need to call is [`tcp_req_conn_keywords_register`](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/fc0b8f39a6497f89cab338fc515f4a922cadecc2/src/tcp_rules.c#L47-L53), but unfortunately that's not exposed to Lua. The only callers of that function are for some hardcoded actions in [proto_tcp.c](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/fc0b8f39a6497f89cab338fc515f4a922cadecc2/src/proto_tcp.c#L1988-L1997) and [stick_table.c](https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/fc0b8f39a6497f89cab338fc515f4a922cadecc2/src/stick_table.c#L3871-L3878):

```c
static struct action_kw_list tcp_req_conn_actions = {ILH, {
        { "set-src",      tcp_parse_set_src_dst },
        { "set-src-port", tcp_parse_set_src_dst },
        { "set-dst"     , tcp_parse_set_src_dst },
        { "set-dst-port", tcp_parse_set_src_dst },
        { "silent-drop",  tcp_parse_silent_drop },
        { /* END */ }
}};

INITCALL1(STG_REGISTER, tcp_req_conn_keywords_register, &tcp_req_conn_actions);
```

```c
static struct action_kw_list tcp_conn_kws = { { }, {
        { "sc-inc-gpc0", parse_inc_gpc0, 1 },
        { "sc-inc-gpc1", parse_inc_gpc1, 1 },
        { "sc-set-gpt0", parse_set_gpt0, 1 },
        { /* END */ }
}};

INITCALL1(STG_REGISTER, tcp_req_conn_keywords_register, &tcp_conn_kws);
```

However, I once again have two pieces of good news:

- If you can put your whitelist in a file, you can use `tcp-request connection reject unless { src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst }` rather than needing to use Lua at all.
- Nothing jumps out at me as a critical reason that this couldn't be supported from Lua, so it may be able to be added to a future release.

Comment: I using lua because i need high frequently update my whitelist (once every few seconds) that's why the file doesn't quite suit me.
Thanks for answering. At least I realized that it was not I who understand something wrong.